# Complex Morlet Wavelet piano sound analysis

Tags: signal-analysis, wavelet

my  project is monophonic music transcription I am using complex Morlet wavelet but over the 1000 Hz complex Morlet does not give all results right, my code is like that ;

```
fc=centfrq('cmor5-5'); % center frequency
fa=1047; % 5 Octave c note
scale=(fc*fs)./(fa);
coef=cwt(data,scale,'cmor5-5');
p=abs((coef).^2);
```

Does anyone give me information about complex Morlet wavelet ?

Comment: looks like today's magic is whatever wavelets whereas yesterday's magic was the FFT.  you remember "FFT this, FFT that."  all we need to do to FFT the data and answers magically fall out, rather than learn and understand what the real problem is.

Comment: I am ploting power with time and mark the peaks ,time axis of peaks give play time of note but over 1000hz I can obtain all notes so all peaks this is my problem . What  is the reason of this